# node-powershell can't get invoke-command to work

Tags: node.js, powershell

I am trying to get some powershell commands to run on a remote computer when I make a POST-request to an endpoint but cant figure out how to get it to work. I can run the same commands from a powershell prompt/ISE on the same computer as the node applikation and it works

But when I try the same using [node-powershell](https://github.com/rannn505/node-powershell/blob/master/docs/intro.md) I get an errormessage: "Principal Gäst was not found."

This works running from a remote using powershell:

```
$Hostname = "HOSTNAME"
$Username = "LANTM\admuser"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Member = "Gäst"

$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
$Session = New-PSSession –ComputerName $Hostname -Credential $Credentials

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administratörer" -Member $Using:Member}
Remove-PSSession $session
```

This does not work running from a node applikation (on the same computer as I tried the pure powershell):

```
const shell = require("node-powershell");
const config = require("./config");

let ps = new shell({
  executionPolicy: "Bypass",
  noProfile: true,
});

let username = config.AK_USER;
let password = config.AK_PASSWORD;

const runPowerShell = async (typeOfOperation, operations) => {

  try {
   if (typeOfOperation === "LocalAdmin") {
      operations.scriptname = "addUserToLocalAdminGroup";
      const response = await addUserToLocalAdminGroup(operations);
      return response
    } else {
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    ps.dispose();
  }
};

const addUserToLocalAdminGroup = async (operations) => {
 
  username = config.LOCAL_ADMIN_USER
  password = config.LOCAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD
  console.log(`LocalAdmin ${username} ${password} ${operations.hostname} ${operations.member}`)
  ps.addCommand(`../../Scripts/${operations.scriptname}.ps1`);
  ps.addArgument(operations.hostname);
  ps.addArgument(username);
  ps.addArgument(password);
  ps.addArgument(operations.member);

  const output = (await ps.invoke()).trim();
    return output;
};

module.exports = { runPowerShell };
```

addUserToLocalAdminGroup.ps1

```
$Hostname = $args[0]
$Username = $args[1]
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $args[2] -AsPlainText -Force
$Member = $args[3]

$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
$Session = New-PSSession –ComputerName $Hostname -Credential $Credentials

#Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {(Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administratörer" -Member $Member), (${function:ScheduleServiceRemoval} | Out-Null)}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {(Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administratörer" -Member $Using:Member)}
Remove-PSSession $session
```

The error-message I get when using postman:

```
Principal Gäst was not found.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Gäst:String) [Add-LocalGroupMember], PrincipalNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PrincipalNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberCommand
    + PSComputerName        : <Hostname>
```

Comment: Does user `Gäst` exist? Try `Get-LocalUser -Name 'Gäst'`. or try `$Member = (Get-LocalUser -Name 'Gäst').SID`

Comment: I am running the node-application on a windows server. And I can run the same command using the powershell-promp/ISE on the same machine and it works. Only when running the script using node-powershell it says that "Gäst" does not exist. Can node-powershell be runned in some other scope or something like that when beeing called from node ?